# How to encrypt and sign a file using OpenPGP on Mac

Tags: macos, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I fear I may have sent a message without encryption when I thought it was being encrypted and signed. I don't use OpenPGP on a Mac too often (I can't remember the last time), so I'm trying to understand what is happening.

First, I right click on the file, then *Services*, and finally *OpenPGP: Encrypt File*. A window floats in the background with a title *`Encrypting file.txt`*:

[image]

At *Choose Recipients* I select and highlight the recipient. I also checked *Sign*:

[image]

The GPGservice runs, flashes a Growl window that encryption is complete, and puts a file on the filesystem named *`file.txt.gpg`*.

Next, I double click on *`file.txt.gpg`*. GPGservice runs again, flashes a Growl message that decryption is complete, and puts another file on the filesystem named *`file 2.txt`*. I then examine *`file 2.txt`*, and its the plaintext message.

I've repeated this four or five times now. The first few times was due to disbelief, the other two were to take screen captures. I'm fairly certain I am describing the exact steps I performed. It also is consistent with the GPGTools support article [How to encrypt and sign text or files with GPGServices?](http://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/gpgservices-faq/how-to-encrypt-and-sign-text-or-files-with-gpgservices)

How is it possible I am decrypting the file encrypted under another's public key? I know its not possible, so what is really happening?

And more importantly, how do I encrypt and sign file using OpenPGP on a Mac? (I have to ask this dumb question because things don't appear to work as advertised or expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible I am decrypting the file encrypted under another's public key? I know its not possible, so what is really happening?

As *Add to Recipients* is checked beneath your own key, the message is not only encrypted for the actual recipient, but also your own key (so you can also decrypt it afterwards).

The safest method to analyze what's contained in an OpenPGP message is probably dropping to the terminal and running `gpg --list-packets [filename]`. For an encrypted message, you will observe lines like

```
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid CC73B287A4388025
```

Each of them indicates that a message is encrypted for this public key, referenced by its key ID. There will be additional lines, don't care about them (the output is not really easy to read and understand if you're not familiar with [RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)).

> And more importantly, how do I encrypt and sign file using OpenPGP on a Mac? (I have to ask this dumb question because things don't appear to work as advertised or expected).

The method you chose seems like a viable one -- if you prefer dropping to the command line, the equivalent would be

```
gpg --recipient [key-id] --output file.txt.gpg --sign --encrypt file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Jens. I never checked the tick box next to my name to make myself a recipient (I repeated this experiment 4 or 5 times). If the check box next to my name was not ticked, then how did the message become encrypted under my public key?

Comment: Have a look at the output of `gpg --list-packets`. Is your key really listed here? If you uncheck that box and your key is still listed, your key might be configured to be added in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` (GPGTools just calls the GnuPG command line utility under the hood) or there is a bug in the software not considering the unchecked add-myself-to-the-recipient-list box.